# Custom angularjs route url

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Currently I'm using Angular Js routing this way and it's working fine.

```
config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider, $mdThemingProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/templates/home.html',
                controller: 'smu72Controller'
            })
       .when('/contact', {
           templateUrl: '/templates/contact.html',
           controller: 'smu72Controller'
       })
            .when('/objects', {
                templateUrl: '/templates/objects.html',
                controller: 'smu72Controller'
            })
            .when('/objects/:objectId', {
                templateUrl: '/templates/object.html',
                controller: 'smu72Controller'
            })
            .when('/services', {
                templateUrl: '/templates/services.html',
                controller: 'smu72Controller'
            })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
    }
    ]);
```

But with this code I got ugly looking and not seo friendly urls as `host/index.html#sectionname`, how should I change this to get route url as `host/sectionname`?

P.S. I'm getting templates to div with `ng-view` on Index.html page.

Comment: Thanks you guys, both answers are correct actually, so I just select oldest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using the `$locationProvider` module and setting `html5Mode` to `true` (the use of HTML5 [History](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) API) we get rid of the ugly `#`

```
config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                 templateUrl: '/templates/home.html',
                 controller: 'smu72Controller'
             })
    /* your all other route specifications */

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

Comment: Dont just dump code, try to add some description as well

Comment: @dreamweiver, you're right, but this answer clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

By default Angular uses something called hashbang mode, you can turn this off and use HTML5 mode - with this you get nice urls - but it won't work in old browsers. To turn this on, put the line below in the config section of your app - remeber to inject `$locationProvider`.

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Read more here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location .